# PHP-FPM taking too much memory

Tags: memory-leaks, php

I am using Nginx+PHP-FPM with php 5.3.6 and it was working well for weeks.
Suddenly each PHP-FPM child started taking too much memory. In initial weeks each PHP-FPM child used to take 3MB now few children are taking 700MB.
Can anybody guide on this?

```
This script I used to get memory usage by child pid 
 http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py.

It could be verified by 'top' method too

top output::
------------------------------
------------------------------
28419 daemon    20   0  844m 757m 4200 S    0  6.4   0:14.27 php-fpm                                                          

16788 daemon    20   0  700m 614m 4632 S    0  5.2   0:28.34 php-fpm                                                          

29450 daemon    20   0  669m 581m 3548 S    0  4.9   0:08.31 php-fpm                                                          

17881 daemon    20   0  642m 556m 4108 S    0  4.7   0:14.83 php-fpm                                                          

19048 daemon    20   0  642m 555m 4108 S    0  4.7   0:08.86 php-fpm 
11956 daemon    20   0 97612  10m 5476 S    4  0.1   0:39.57 php-fpm                                                          
11993 daemon    20   0 97560  10m 5188 S    4  0.1   0:39.18 php-fpm                                                          
11925 daemon    20   0 97328  10m 5144 D    3  0.1   0:38.68 php-fpm                                                          
11953 daemon    20   0 97748  10m 5172 S    4  0.1   0:38.51 php-fpm
```

php-fpm.conf:

```
/etc/php-fpm/php-fpm.conf
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
user = daemon
group = daemon

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 2000
pm.start_servers = 50
pm.min_spare_servers = 40
pm.max_spare_servers = 90
pm.max_requests = 10000
```

Following are the more debug inputs:

pmap::

```
pmap 28419
0000000000b52000     96K rw---    [ anon ]
0000000001a49000   1668K rw---    [ anon ]
0000000001bea000    208K rw---    [ anon ]
0000000001c1e000 770476K rw---    [ anon ]
```

strace::

```
strace -p 28419
Process 28419 attached - interrupt to quit
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...>) = 0
recvfrom(4, 0x1bda1d0, 8196, 64, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 0 (Timeout)
recvfrom(4, 0x1bda1d0, 8196, 64, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000^C <unfinished ...>
```

Comment: may be a too ignorant comment - any chance your PHP scripts started to eat too much memory - by loading too much data for example?

Comment: Is your site busy? What's the # of requests per minute? This could some memory leak in one of your php libraries, which is common in php. :)

Comment: Have you checked your slowlog? It's defined in your php-fpm config file.

Comment: Based on your setting: pm.min_spare_servers = 40, you should have at least 40 idle php processes in your top output. This is too big! Could you list all of the php-fpm info? For example, run 'ps aux |grep php-fpm |grep -v grep'

Answer (score 10):

Try lowering pm.max_requests to 1000 and then lower if needed. This will kill off the child processes after 1000 requests. There are many variables to consider when php-fpm hogs resources. I have been using it for quite a while and have not seen this level of memory consumption. My guess would be a code issue, or a run-away script.

Comment: Right. This is the main tool to fight against 3rd party library memory leaks.

Comment: The only thing that work for me is opcache http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php